# Passing parameters with tap function in nativescript

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, nativescript

I want to do something like this, but it's not working in this way.
Here's xml code:

```
<image id="CustomerRadioButton" src="{{ CustomerRBSrc }}" class="RadioButton" tap="CustomerTypeRadioButtonOnTap('C')"/>
```

And how can I get this parameter in js code?

Comment: How are you using nativescript? Are you using it with Angular?

Comment: No, vanilla js. Sorry for replying late, took too long as i got distracted and busy :/

Comment: OK. So it is vanilla JS, but the code you have in your question is an XML template, not JavaScript. What I was asking was this: "What framework is interpreting the `{{expression}}` syntax? Is it VueJS, AngularJS, Angular 2.0+, or something else?" For example if you are using NativeScript with Aurelia then `{{expression}}` is invalid syntax and you need to write `${expression}` instead. Be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

There is a couple ways you can handle this in a PAN (Plain Awesome Nativescript) app.

1. You can call a custom function that then calls the proper function i.e. the button is set to:
   `CustomerTypeRadioButtonOnTapC = () { CustomerTypeRadioButtonOnTap('C'); }`
2. You can set a custom property on the image - i.e. 
   `<image id="CustomerRadioButton" src="{{ CustomerRBSrc }}" class="RadioButton" tap="CustomerTypeRadioButtonOnTap" customerType="C"/>`

then the

```
 function CustomerTypeRadioButtonOnTab (args) {
     console.log(args.object.customerType);  // Should be "C" 
 }
```